# How to append to an hdfs file on an extremely small cluster (3 nodes or less)

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to append to a file on an hdfs on a single node cluster. I also tried on a 2 node cluster but get the same exceptions.

In hdfs-site, I have `dfs.replication` set to 1. If I set `dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy` to `DEFAULT` I get the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[10.10.37.16:50010], original=[10.10.37.16:50010]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
```

If I follow the recommendation in the comment for the [configuration in hdfs-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) for extremely small clusters (3 nodes or less) and set `dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy` to `NEVER` I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot append to file/user/hadoop/test. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 1277 has reached the threshold 1.0000 of total blocks 1277. The number of live datanodes 1 has reached the minimum number 0. In safe mode extension. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 3 seconds.
```

Here's how I try to append:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://MY-MACHINE:8020/user/hadoop");
conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hadoop");

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
OutputStream out = fs.append(new Path("/user/hadoop/test"));

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
writer.print("hello world");
writer.close();
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in the code? 
maybe, there is something missing in the configuration?
Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Even though that `dfs.replication` is set to `1`, when I check the status of the file through

```
FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/hadoop"));
```

I find that `status[i].block_replication` is set to `3`. I don't think that this the problem because when I changed the value of `dfs.replication` to `0` I got a relevant exception. So apparently it does indeed obey the value of `dfs.replication` but to be on the safe side, is there a way to change the `block_replication` value per file?

Comment: I guess for a single node cluster the replication should be zero, and what is the value for dfs.support.append?

Comment: @sambhavSharma I tried to set it to 0 but it also threw an exception that there's no live datanodes and dfs.support.append is indeed set to true

Comment: Yepp, the replication needs to be 1

Comment: @peeskillet I think the issue is different, here, safe mode gets turned off automatically in a couple of seconds and I can operate anything normally, however, if I try to append it gets into it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mentioned in the edit. Even though the `dfs.replication` is set to `1`, `fileStatus.block_replication` is set to 3.

A possible solution is to run

```
hadoop fs -setrep -w 1 -R /user/hadoop/
```

Which will change the replication factor for each file recursively in the given directory. Documentation for the command can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html#setrep).

What to be done now is to look why the value in hdfs-site.xml is ignored. And how to force the value `1` to be the default.

**EDIT**

It turns out that the `dfs.replication` property has to be set in the `Configuration` instance too, otherwise it requests that the replication factor for the file be the default which is 3 regardless of the value set in hdfs-site.xml

Adding to the code the following statement will solve it.

```
conf.set("dfs.replication", "1");
```

Comment: To make things clearer for future reference: the solution for new files is to add conf.set("dfs.replication", "1") to the FileSystem.get configuration. For existing files, running hadoop fs -setrep -w 1 /user/hadoop/ is also necessary  (-R is ignored in current versions).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same exception as you initially posted and I solved the problem thanks to your comments (set dfs.replication to 1).

But I don't understand something, what happens if I do have replication? In that case isn't it possible to append to a file?

I will appreciate your answer and if you had an experience with it.

Thanks

Comment: When you have replication, you have to make sure that the replication factor is less than or equal to the number of your datanodes.
The reason why writing for the first time succeeds and appending fails when the replication factor is greater than the number of datanodes is that appending is more strict to ensure consistency whereas writing for the first time can tolerate under-replication. 
p.s. your input would have been more suitable as a comment than as an answer